# How to add new id ( which is already deleted in database ) using haruncpi / laravel-id-generator

Tags: laravel

I am using IdGenerator and this is good shortcut to add new ID with out any errors.
Now i created new ID say Cust-01, Cust-02, Cust-03... Meantime i deleted "Cust-02" id from database so my new id data is Cust-01, Cust-03 and so on After i create new id it start with "Cust-04" whereas i wanted to get is Cust-02.
How can i do the same.
Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator

```
$cowid = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'cowdata','field'=>'cowID', 'length' => 6, 'prefix' =>'Cow-']);
```

Comment: Maybe you should set manually your auto increment in your mySql, in this case, is the Cust-01 is the primary key?

Comment: No. my primary Key is "id" with AI..

Comment: So can try to pass `reset_on_prefix_change => true`

Comment: ok....will do and update the status..Thanks